# Printing lines from a CSV file with fgets()

Tags: c, file-io

When I run the following function, the output is "Line is:" and the next line is left blank. I think I have some flawed understanding of how pointers and strings work. The file is opening correctly and the line is being read correctly, otherwise my error messages would be printed, and no warnings or error messages are appearing in the console. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

UPDATED CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    char filename[152];
    sprintf(filename, "%s", argv[1]);
    printf("%s", filename);

    FILE* stream = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(!stream){
        printf("\nError: File could not be read\n");
    }
    char line[1000];
    if(fgets(line, 1000, stream) == NULL){
        printf("\nError: Line could not be read\n");
    } else {
        printf("Line is:\n");
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the csv file:

```
125779,Sofiya Aleksandrovna Velikaya,F,23,175,70,Russia,RUS,2008 Summer,2008,Summer,Beijing,Fencing,"Fencing Women's Sabre, Individual",NA
60890,Toshiaki Kitai,M,28,NA,NA,Japan,JPN,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Equestrianism,"Equestrianism Men's Jumping, Individual",NA
31299,Iera Echebarra Fernndez,F,23,160,63,Spain,ESP,2016 Summer,2016,Summer,Rio de Janeiro,Rugby Sevens,Rugby Sevens Women's Rugby Sevens,NA
28351,Adalbert Dickhut,M,29,NA,NA,Germany,GER,1952 Summer,1952,Summer,Helsinki,Gymnastics,Gymnastics Men's Pommelled Horse,NA
99701,James Reid,M,24,180,70,South Africa,RSA,2016 Summer,2016,Summer,Rio de Janeiro,Cycling,"Cycling Men's Mountainbike, Cross-Country",NA
132730,Reza Mohammad Ali Yazdani,M,23,172,100,Iran,IRI,2008 Summer,2008,Summer,Beijing,Wrestling,"Wrestling Men's Light-Heavyweight, Freestyle",NA
129830,Ernst Theodor Georgsson Westerlund,M,50,NA,NA,Raili,FIN,1948 Summer,1948,Summer,London,Sailing,Sailing Mixed 6 metres,NA
95980,Julie Pomagalski,F,25,161,60,France,FRA,2006 Winter,2006,Winter,Torino,Snowboarding,Snowboarding Women's Parallel Giant Slalom,NA
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `data.csv`.

Comment: Not difrectly related, but consider what happens if the file could not be opened. You see the problem?

Comment: Your program should print the first line of your csv file. I can't see what's wrong apart from the problem reported in my previous comment, but if the file actually exists, your program should work. Please [edit]  your question and show the first couple of lines of your csv file

Comment: Updated. I've been having issues accessing pointers in a number of applications, even so far as copying code from other sources directly and having issues. Could it be anything to do with static and dynamically allocated arrays?

Comment: Also consider inceasing the buffer size from 152 to say 1000. But even if the buffer size is too small, ypoiur program should output the start of the line.

Comment: Double check that the CSV file does not have empty line at the begin.

Comment: That was the issue. Not sure whether to feel relieved that this problem is solved, or disappointed in my stupidity. Thanks heaps for all the help.

Comment: Was the issue, that the line buffer was too small or that your CSV file started with an empty line? Either way please write it as an answer, to make it easier for future readers that may have a similar problem

Comment: The CSV had a leading line break, I believe. Opening it in notepad, it wasn't visible. But opening it in Excel showed that the first line of data was empty.

Answer (score 0):

It is typical for stdlib not to flush output until a '\n'.

I would either do

```
printf("Line is: %s\n", line);
```

or

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before you quit the program